# jmeter how to fail in artificial way sampler

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to fail a sampler in case the script logically is not right, this is my script:

```
for(int i=0;i<suggestions.length();i++){

                JSONObject item = (JSONObject)suggestions.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject params = item.getJSONObject("params");

                if(i==0){

                        msg = getMessage(item,i,suggestions);
                        System.out.println(msg+" "+ i);
                        if(!msg.equals("Hi, I just started a run at home")){
                                res = result(res);
                                System.out.println(res);
                }
            }
```

Now `result()` function suppose to get failure result string I want to be able to fail the sampler in case the `result()` function output is "fail".

Comment: Hi, do you have to to fail it programitcally? What about an assertion on the response - it would also be easier to maintain.

Comment: The issue is that the response would be probably good in case the string from the response wont be right i want to fail the sampler...

Answer (score 1):

Try  http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Response_Assertion. You can check the String response here. It is better to check here than hard-coding.

Comment: This is my logical script that I am using:

for(int i=0;i<WORK_LENGTH;i++){
  JSONObject item = (JSONObject)suggestions.getJSONObject(i);
     
     if((i==0)||(i==2)){
          msg = getMessage(item,i,suggestions);
          System.out.println(msg+" "+ i);
          if(!msg.equals("Hey, I just left work. Call me if you need anything.")){
            System.out.println("Test failed");
           
      }
     }

When I get to the point the test is failed by writing to console: "Failed", I want as well as writing output to console to fail the sampler itself, how can i do that?

Comment: What kind of sampler are you using? Is it BeanShell sampler?

Comment: BeanShell PostProcessor

Comment: So you have a sampler with BeanShell PostProcessor. Is the only purpose of the PostProcessor to verify the response? If so, use rather BeanShell assertion. It is well-documented in the official documention plus there is a simple script to get you started http://jmeter.apache.org/demos/BeanShellAssertion.bsh. You can see how to fail the request from there.